# Solving a differential equation involving logarithms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of $$ \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{y}{x} =  \frac{1}{(1+\log x+\log y)^2} $$

The correct answer is : $$ xy[1+(ln(xy))^2]=x^2+c$$
My attempt: I tried to consider $y=vx$, but that didn't help me.

Any hint to solve this problem will be very much helpful.

Comment: don't exspect an explicit solution

Comment: That substitution would work much better if one of the logs had a minus sign.

Comment: You should include the provided answer into your question, even though I doubt it's correct: it should be $xy(1+(\log xy)^2)=c+x^2/2$.

Comment: Added the right answer and the solution. Thanks @ProfessorVector and TZakrevskiy.

Answer (score 3):

If you put $z(x) = xy(x)$, then you get
$$\frac{z'}{x} = \frac{1}{(1+\ln z)^2}.$$
Use the separation of variables, the result quickly follows.

UPD: the provided answer does not satisfy the initial differential equation =)

Comment: A result quickly follows, but it's not the one the OP was given as answer.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Indeed. If you differentiate the provided answer with respect to $x$, then you obtain the identity $(y+xy')(1+\ln(xy))^2=0$, which does not agree with the given differential equation. However, the solution you posted in you other comment, is, of course, correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $z=xy$ and differentiating $z$ w.r.t. x, we get
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=x\frac{dy}{dx}+y$$
Hence, the given equation can be rewritten as
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{x}{(1+lnz)^2}$$
$$or,(1+lnz)^2dz=xdx$$
Integrating both sides, we get:
$$\int(1+lnz)^2dz=\int{x}dx$$
$$or, z(1+lnz)^2-2(z.lnz)=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$
$$or, xy(1+ln(xy))^2-2(xy.ln(xy))=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$
$$or, xy[(1+ln(xy))^2-2(ln(xy))]=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$
$$or, xy[1+(ln(xy))^2]=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$